# Examples of sets which measure cannot be obtained by discretisation

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I started reading ["An introduction to measure theory" by Terence Tao](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf). On page 23 on a pdf reader (pg 7 in the actual document), we are asked to think of an example of a set $E\subset$ $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\mathbb{R}^d$ which measure cannot be obtained by discretisation, i.e. such that

[image]

does not exist, where

[image]

and $\#$ denotes the cardinality of the set. I have two questions:

1) I have come up with the following example and I'd like to check whether it actually work, as I am not certain I understood the measure correctly.

> > $E := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y = \frac{1}{2},~x\in [0,1]\}$

If I understand the measure right, as $N = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\dots$, $m(E) = 0, \frac{3}{2},0 \frac{5}{4},0,\frac{7}{6},\dots$ hence the limit does not exist. Is this correct?

2) Do you know of simpler/ more enlightening examples?

Comment: your idea is not correct, since your example is two-dimensional. The set $E\cap\frac{1}{N}\mathbb Z^2$ has $N+1$ elements if $N$ is even, and is empty if $N$ is odd. But then you devide by $N^2$!

Comment: @Martin Van der Linden: I can't find anything like what you say on page 23 of the document that you reference. Have you considered the possibility that $E \cap \frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}$ might be empty for every $N$, but $E$ might have non-zero Lebesgue measure?

Comment: The reference is correct, and the question above was asked within the explanation why such a measure is not good in general. I'm thinking of another example atm... There should be an example in $\mathbb R$...

Comment: @sranthrop: apologies: you saw a version of my comment that was posted in error. I still can't see anything like what the OP describes on page 23 of the document. Hence I can't verify whether the "obvious" answer to the question is correct.

Comment: @ Rob : Sorry for the confusion, I referred to the pagination of the pdf reader, which means it's on page 7 in the actual document.

Comment: @ both of you : My bad, $\mathbb{R}$ was a typo, as you'll see in the document, it was meant to be $\mathbb{R}^d$. I edit. Apart from that, I did not understand what the $d$ in exponent of the $N$ was a power, and mistakenly treated $N^d$ as $N$...

Comment: The text is actually asking you to find an $E$ such that the limit does not exist (which is not quite how Martin has phrased his question). It exists for any bounded $E$. You can construct unbounded $E$ such that the intersection is finite for each $N$ but the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Martin: Your example was not that bad :) Maybe we can use the following example for the one-dimensional case, which is a modification of yours. Define $E$ as the set of all rationals between 0 and 1 with even denominator. Then $E\cap\frac{1}{N}\mathbb Z$ is empty iff $N$ is an odd prime, but has $N-1$ elements if $N$ is a power of 2.

Comment: @sranthrop: my last comment was wrong - you should post your example as the answer to the question.

Comment: I am not sure if comments on a post is the best way to follow this discussion but @Rob: I'd be interested to hear more about how my formulation differ from the problem proposed in the book @ Both of you : it seems that your last two comments conflict with each other as sranthrop proposed a bounded solution.

Comment: @Rob : Then we are set. I agree about posting your comment as answer, this would close the question.

Comment: @Martin: I withdrew my comment. If one knows a bit of measure theory, the "obvious" answer to your question as you stated it (by saying "measure cannot be obtained by discretisation") is $E = [0, 1] \mathop{\backslash} \mathbb{Q}$ which has Lebesgue measure $1$ but has $m(E) = 0$. In the context of a discussion in a textbook prior to the definition of Lebesgue measure, that is not appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is not correct, since your example is two-dimensional. The set $E\cap\frac{1}{N}\mathbb Z$ has $N+1$ elements if $N$ is even, and is empty if $N$ is odd. But then you devide by $N^2$, which gives you 0 for the limit in any case.

However, your example was not that bad :) Maybe we can use the following example for the one-dimensional case, which is a modification of yours. Define 
$$
E=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\in(0,1)\ |\ b\mbox{ is even}\right\}
$$ 
as the set of all rationals between 0 and 1 with even denominator. Then $E\cap\frac{1}{N}\mathbb Z$ is empty iff $N$ is an odd prime, but has $N−1$ elements if $N$ is a power of 2. Thus, the limit cannot exist.

Comment: However, I question if this example is "better" ore more enlightening...

Comment: A last thing : given my edit changing $\mathbb{R}$ for $\mathbb{R}^d$ (and notwithstanding the fact that a simpler example could be found on $\mathbb{R}$), the fact that my example was two dimensional was not the real problem or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you can, of course, find a two (or in general $d$ dimensional ) example. The problem with your example was, that $E$ had too little elements to adjust the division by $N^2$.
For a $d$-dimensional example, use my $E$ and change it to $E^d$. This should work...

Comment: Yep, the exponent on the $N$ was clearly the part I overlooked...

Comment: I assume you mean where a and b are co prime? Otherwise every rational number can be written in that form.

Comment: yes, sure. Thx :)